P(sup_t $\vert X^{t}_n - X^{t}\vert$) vs sup_t P($\vert X^{t}_n - X^{t}\vert$) in probability theory
I have a question regarding probability theory which has to do with the notion of uniform convergence in probability. One considers a sequence of random variables $X_n^{t}$ parametrized by a parameter $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I assume that $X_n^{t} \rightarrow X^{t}$ in probability for every $t$ and i want to investigate the possibility of uniform convergence. I consider the two statements
$$ \lim_{\ n \rightarrow \infty} P(\mathrm{sup}_{t \  \in \mathbb{R}} \vert X^{t}_n - X^{t}\vert > \epsilon) = 0 $$ and
$$\lim_{\ n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{sup}_{t \  \in \mathbb{R}} P(\vert X^{t}_n - X^{t}\vert > \epsilon ) = 0$$
for every $\epsilon > 0$.
My qustion is: is the first statement stronger and therefore implying the second one ? Naively i would think that the maximum probability is reached at the maximum distance between $X^{t}_n$ and $X_n$, but probably i am missing some subtleties regarding probability space topology. Thank you very much.

Yes, the first one implies the second. Reason: $P( \vert X^{s}n - X^{s}\vert > \epsilon) \le P(\mathrm{sup}{t \  \in \mathbb{R}} \vert X^{t}_n - X^{t}\vert > \epsilon)$ for any $s$. Take sup over $s$.

thank you very much for your answer. I understand what you mean. Do you think one can state some conditions for which the inequality becomes an equality? Thank you again.
